# How to replace global function while doing unit test with jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm working on writing unit test for a module. And I really need help for handling the global vars & functions.
I simply my question as follows:
Let's say the module I want to test on named 'needTest.js'. It structures as this:

[image]

Since I only need to test main function in needTest.js, in my test file, I first `import main from '../needTest.js'`. And my question is: function main does not only need three inputs p1, p2 and p3, it also depends on some global var or functions such as isA, isB, isC. How do I mock those globals in my test file? I want to simply replace the return values of those globals and let my test file ignore what it used to import but only use what I mocked.

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this would be by using Jest's [`jest.mock` method](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/jest-object.html#jestmockmodulename-factory-options).

```
jest.mock('module-isA-came-from');
jest.mock('module-isB-came-from');
jest.mock('module-isC-came-from');
```

You can then either explicitly pass a module factory:

```
jest.mock('module-isA-came-from', () => jest.fn(() => 42));
```

Or set the expectation on the automocked module:

```
isA.mockReturnValue(42);
```